# How to disable the autocomplete red border in PhpStorm for PHP functions

Tags: phpstorm

With the update to PhpStorm 2016.1.1, when I pick a function from the list that PhpStorm suggests in autocomplete, it will insert variables in the function arguments with a red border.

Is there any way to disable the injection of the variables and the red border but keep the function name autocomplete?

[image: example]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. `Settings/Preferences`
2. `Editor | General | Smart Keys`
3. Disable `PHP | Enable smart function parameters completion` option

[image]

Comment: I wish I could upvote this a 100 times. I have searched the settings for this without any luck. Now I can finally get rid of that horrible red box. Great example of when assistance becomes counter productive.

Comment: Thanks so much! What a terrible default setting. *shudders*